# How to use version numbers and shared library suffix (.so or .dylib) in CMake

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, dylib, cpack

In CMake I'm installing a shared library that installs installs fine on my Linux machine as libname.so.1.5.0
However, for compatability with Macs I have to support using any shared library suffix. I set up my CMake to install `${libnameCMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}.${OPENTRACING_VERSION_STRING}` which once again works on my machine but not on Macs. The .dylibs that get generated for some reason have the naming convention of libname.1.5.0.dylib
Is there any way I can

1. Change either naming convention to the other?
2. Have CMake detect system architecture and have multiple calls?
3. Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated! I've never used OSX so not sure about how .dylibs work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could tell this was impossible to do without just hacking them in if/else branches. I settled on adding commands to my `INSTALL` calls that directly moved the files I needed. It ended up copying extra unnecessary files but was the only thing I could figure out that worked.